# how can I order an postgresql table so that consecutive values do not match

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I write an postgresql query or view that returns a table where it’s first results do not have any matching consecutive values in a given column.
For example on this table:

```
+--------------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
|            id            | model |      name      | colour |
+--------------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| 59663f188b06e815cae676f4 | ford  | amazing car    | red    |
| 59663f1487b60515ca614999 | ford  | great car      | pink   |
| 59663f230f519115cae6e089 | mini  | broken car     | blue   |
| 59663f1ce28a5315ca07262e | vw    | mystery mobile | blue   |
+--------------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
```

If I choose model or colour the order could be:

```
+--------------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
|            id            | model |      name      | colour |
+--------------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| 59663f188b06e815cae676f4 | ford  | amazing car    | red    |
| 59663f230f519115cae6e089 | mini  | broken car     | blue   |
| 59663f1487b60515ca614999 | ford  | great car      | pink   |
| 59663f1ce28a5315ca07262e | vw    | mystery mobile | blue   |
+--------------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It probably works if the data has more than one duplicate values

```
Select 
   id
  ,model
  ,name
  ,colour
  ,row_number() over(partition by model) Rno
from Table
order by Rno
```

Comment: That appears to group them by model. I am looking to shuffle them so that no two consecutive models match

Comment: It is not grouping. Try to execute it over your table and see

Comment: No, you are totally right. that works a charm. Thank you ever so much.